What is the highest scoring round that could be played in a 2 person game of cribbage?
me and my family were enjoying a game of cribbage the other night when we discussed the highest possible hand a player could score. Traditionally this is said to be 29 (555J with cut card 5 (suit matching J)) but we began to debate this and discovered that if you are the dealer, you could score an additional point for nibs (5555 with cut card J + nibs). After this was realized a heated debate began about the highest possible scoring round which could theoretically be played in cribbage. Each round of cribbage includes 5 components which a player could receive points for: The cut card, pegging, the normal hand, opponents missed points, and finally the crib.  After a lengthy discussion we ended up agreeing that scoring 84 points is the highest amount a player could score in any given round. This is how our 84 point game was dealt.
The deck begins with the top cards stacked 5K5K5Q5QKKQQ, You are dealt 5555QK and your opponent KKKQQQ Each of you put a Q and K into the crib so the final hands are (5555, QQKK, [QQKK]). Play begins by cutting the deck to a J and you, the dealer, score +2 points for nibs. After cutting pegging ensues and given the cards in play you automatically win +6 points because the non-dealer always pegs first. (Order of play [card.count + points] <K.10, 5.15 +2, K.25, 5.30, Go +1, Q.10 + 5.15 +2, Q.25, 5.last_card.30 +1> [+2+1+2+1=6]). After pegging each player counts up their hand. Your opponent is a new player, who is already frustrated over a previous game, slams down his KKQQ in anger shouting "I never get any 15s!", you feel slightly bad but after he demanded his turn be over you steal +24 points from his awesome hand and then move on to your own. Your 5555+J scores you a nice +28. You flip your crib over and are greeted by another sweet +24 points. All in all you score 84 points that round. [+2+6+24+28+24=84]. Is this the highest possible scoring round of cribbage that could be played? It's the most obvious but could you score higher using low cards or a different method?
Additionally, what are the chances of this happening in a real game? Here are the probabilities I calculated: [I don't know whether the top 12 cards should be calculated (1/52)(1/51)(1/50)...etc or ((1/52)^12 or some other method, so I went with the first mentioned.]
Chance the top 12 cards are 5K5KQ5Q5KKQQ: 1/9.88561E19
Chance your opponent throws the QK into the crib: 2/6
Chance you are the dealer: 1/2
Chance the cut card is a J: 1/40
Chance your opponent misses points: 1/2
Total odds: 1/4.74509E22
So if my math is correct the chances of you scoring an 84-point round is 1 out of 47.5 sextillion?
Should this question be posted in a different exchange?


If you [edit] the question to delete (or at least postpone) the description of the game and ask just about the probability question at the end we may be able to help. There only the first, third and fourth items have a mathematical answer.
